# Using Heroku SSL (ACM) alongside AWS S3 / Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, heroku, amazon-s3, https

I have an application running on Heroku, using S3 and cloudfront for all its assets and user uploads. I need to move this application over to HTTPS. All assets are served from a subdomain of my application: `media.example.com`.

Heroku offers [free Automated Certificate Management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management) (ACM) for paid apps which updates the certificate automatically with the 90 day limit of 
 the certificates it uses from Let's Encrypt. However, because I am serving assets from a custom subdomain, I can't use Amazon's default certificate. This would would be fine if the assets were served from cloudfront domain:

`https://daada2m06ffg6ds.cloudfront.net`,

but not using a custom subdomain:

`https://media.example.com`.

As far as I can see this will mean I need to copy across the updated certificate to AWS Certificate Manager every time it updates. Is this correct? If so, what are my options for handling this syncing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't have to use the same identical SSL certificate in both places. Amazon has its own ACM service (Amazon Certificate Manager). When you request a free certificate from Amazon Certificate Manager it will also automatically update the certificate, similar to Heroku's ACM service.

Enable the Heroku certificate to get SSL on the resources Heroku is serving. Then go into AWS and go to the Amazon Certificate Manager service and request a free SSL certificate there as well. Then add that Amazon certificate to your CloudFront distribution.

Comment: By the way, for the AWS ACM certificate to be available for use in CloudFront you have to create the certificate in the `us-east-1` region.

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful.